# How to 'cd' to a docker port address instead of running a docker command?

Tags: bash, docker, cd

I'm trying to run the commmand  `sudo docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash`, but I'm getting the result `Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint stupefied_pare... Bind for 0.0.0.0:9000 failed: port is already allocated.` I know this has something to do with the fact that I have ran this command previously, but I was wondering how I  cd into the docker port I previously allocated instead of attempting (and failing) to allocated it again whenever I open a terminal.
Edit: Question is answered in comments

Comment: Eh? `cd` is "change directory". What does it have to do with TCP ports?

Comment: Sorry, that's just my way of rationalizing it. I'm unfamiliar with how TCP ports work...but I was just wondering how I change directory (or whatever appropriate terminology is used with ports) to the port I was previously working in

Comment: You can't have two processes retrieving traffic for the same port on the same interface at once -- perhaps what you want to do is shut the old container down before you start a new one? Or maybe you want to attach to the old docker container instead of starting a new one? Regardless, the question should be edited to make it more clear what you want and thus what you're asking.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that previously when I ran the command, it allocated a TCP port and then redirected me into the port. Now when I run it, it throws an error because the port is already allocated. I'm not trying to reallocate the port, I'm just trying to be directed into it.

Comment: "Redirected me to the port"? What does that even mean?

Comment: If what you mean is that it attached your terminal to a bash instance that had the port mapped to it... yup, that's exactly what it did, and you can use `docker attach` to reconnect if the container is still up.

Comment: docker attach, but what would the third command be?

Comment: Do you mean the third *argument*? The id of the container you previously started with `docker run`, of course.

Comment: So...-p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash ?

Comment: no, the *id* of the container, as given in the output of `docker ps`.

Comment: Huzzzah, that works, but how to shut down the docker so that it's not draining my battery?

Comment: This is Docker for Mac? Go up to the little whale icon, click on it, and go to "Quit Docker". You need to actually shut down the VM, not the individual containers that run in it, to have useful effect on your battery life. An idle container that's just running `bash` is going to have basically no effect on your battery -- much less than the VM it runs inside of.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu in the termianl

Comment: Ahh. In *that* case, Docker isn't draining your battery substantially anyhow, since it's just a bunch of idle processes using the same kernel you use for everything else; the only difference is the namespace they exist in. That said, if it makes you feel better, `docker kill` exists.

Comment: Oh OK, that works